# Gradle copy folder on installDist

Tags: gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

Using gradle 3.4 but fairly new to it.

If I run gradlew installDist the files in src/main/java get copied to the build folder all that works fine.

But I also have an extra folder in src/main/conf I would like to copy over to build/install/my-artifact/conf

I don't want to put it in src/main/resources because that will get included inside the jar. I would like to keep it external.

My gradle file doesn't have anything special except the dependencies.

So how would I go about copying the folders/files when installDist runs?

EDIT:

Has to work with shadow plugin as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manage [distribution contents](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html#sec:distribution_contents), you will need to modify the `main` distribution like the following :

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        baseName = 'my-artifact'
        contents {
            from { 'src/main/java' }
            from('src/main') {
                include 'conf/**'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will :

- copy the files under `src/main/java`
- copy the directory `conf` and the files under it

The new structure would be like :

```
build/install/my-artifact/
                   │
                   ├── com/
                   │   └── yourlib
                   │       └── ......
                   └── conf/
                       └── .....
```

You could also include the source directory at the same level :

```
build/install/my-artifact/
                   │
                   ├── java/
                   │    └── com/
                   │         └── yourlib
                   │               └── ......     
                   └── conf/
                        └── .....
```

with the following :

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        baseName = 'my-artifact'
        contents {
            from('src/main') {
                include 'java/**'
                include 'conf/**'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check [CopySpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html) interface for more info

Comment: Ok that seems to work. I wasn't sure if it's the same or not, but can this be done with the shadow versions installShadowApp and distShadowZip (updated question)?

Comment: Did you try [that workaround](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/150) ?

Comment: Yeah that works. installShadowApp {
  distributions {
    contents {
      from('src/main') {
        include 'conf/**'
      }
      from ('.') {
        include 'webroot/**'
      }
    }
  }
}